# bind angular scope object returned from web api to dropdown

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am unsuccessful in binding a scope object returned from a service to a dropdown (ng-model=ProdCategoryId) to show as selected item. I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

```
Controller.js

 $scope.GetSingleProduct = function (prod) {
    var getsingleprod = ProductService.GetSingleProduct(prod.ProdId);
    getsingleprod.then(function (pl) {
        var singleproddetails = pl.data;
        $scope.ProdCategoryId = singleproddetails[0].ProdCategoryId;
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("Err" + err);
    });

HTML

 <select ng-model="ProdCategoryId" class="form-control"
                            ng-options="item as item.ProdCategoryName for item in catlist|orderBy:'ProdCategoryName'">
                        <option value="">Choose Category</option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: Where are you setting up catlist and what is the object structure?

Comment: Please post your json that web api is returning. This can be obtained from the network tab in the browser

Answer (score 0):

most likely angular does not know that your model changed, depending on what your service is doing. You will need to call $scope.apply() as in below:

```
$scope.GetSingleProduct = function (prod) {
var getsingleprod = ProductService.GetSingleProduct(prod.ProdId);
getsingleprod.then(function (pl) {
    var singleproddetails = pl.data;
    $scope.ProdCategoryId = singleproddetails[0].ProdCategoryId;
    $scope.apply()
}, function (err) {
    console.log("Err" + err);
});
```

here is a useful writeup on this: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: this solution is not working for me when i put $scope.apply()